# Discord.js: Console Log all members with role ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to console log all members listed in the console with a role id.

My Code currently is:

```js
const test = client.guilds.cache.forEach(g =>
g.members.cache.filter(member =>
member.roles.cache.has("705445368694833245"))) console.log(test)
```

When someone join it will display "undefined" in the console.
Any solutions at this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got the solution:

```js
let users = ``;
client.guilds.cache.forEach(g => {
  g.members.cache.forEach(m => {
    if (m.roles.cache.has(`ROLE ID`)) {
      users += `${m.user.tag}\n`
    }
  })
})
console.log(users);
```

And when i try to log more than one role, what is the best option to do that?